# ASP.NET Alternative to Shorty

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, url-routing

Does anyone know of an ASP.NET alternative available for Shorty (http://get-shorty.com/)?

Comment: Too hard to create yourself? Shouldn't be that hard. Someone suggested using crc16/crc32 for creating the urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never did find a pre-built package for ASP.NET -- wrote my own but eventually migrated to Bitly.Pro. The API and tracking information was worth the move.

Answer (score 1):

Silly question, but if these are URL redirects that live on your servers (rather than an external service)...why not just use IIS folder redirects?